# How to do trim columns when loading data using AWS DMS

Tags: aws-dms, dms

I have to migrate tables using AWS DMS. While loading I have to trim the columns in source table and load it to target. I was not able to find any transformation rule for trim in AWS DMS. How it can be achieved?

Comment: What is AWS DMS? Are you referring to "RedShift" ?

Comment: @GeoffGriswald  AWS Database Migration Service

Answer (score 0):

Could you perform a `remove-prefix` and `remove-suffix` as a means to trim your data? [Guide on how to do that here.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/transformations-aws-dms/)

Alternatively you can trigger a Lambda to do trimming, every time new data are added to your target location.